# Recommended strategy for bulk processing in backend using NetCore and Mongo DB

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, bulk

we currently have a collection with approximately 4 million documents.

One of our backend processes requires to use those 4 million documents. Apply one-to-one update operations on these documents using information from documents in other collections.

Currently our idea is to load all the documents in memory in the backend (NetCore 3.1) and process them one by one, but we would like to know if in your experience there is any other mechanism that is more efficient, more secure and less expensive at the level of resources.

Comment: don't load all 4 million docs into memory at once. get a cursor and load batches of 100 or so docs at a time. be prepared for many hours of processing though. write a console app with some sort of progress display so you know it's working as expected and not stuck.

Comment: Have you seen aggregation pipeline of MongoDB. Why don't you try query instead of bringing data into in memory and doing operation. There is lookup stage to join the two collection https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/